# Associate a time-threshold with a message in kafka

Tags: delay, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way I can have time threshold associated message in Kafka. 
E.g.
Consumer pulls a message out of Kafka but system does not have enough information to process. So I put the message back in "resolver" queue, but I do not want to pull it out of the "resolver" queue for next 15 minutes, is there any way I can achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve that with just Kafka. Kafka is designed to store messages for a certain period of time or until a certain size. The only way to get messages from Kafka is by offset. The offset identifies which messages have been consumed, messages before the offset have already been read, messages after the offset are yet to be read.

As far as I know Kafka does not provide time stamps with its messages (I could be wrong about that). But reading through the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) and working with it for several months I have never encountered any example about retrieving messages from Kafka based on time.